# Getting the category type from a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display the category that a post is from inside of a badge from boostrap, however I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't display anything.

My current code has this:

```
<?php

$result = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
'numberposts' => 10,
'category' => '',
'post_status' => 'publish',
));

foreach( $result as $p ){
?>

<div class="paddingarea text-dark">

   <div class="the-image">
       <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($p['ID'], array(302, 170)); ?>" /></a>
   </div>
   <a href="#" class="badge badge-primary"><?php
   foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {
   echo $category;
  }
   ?></a>
   <a class="card-title" href="<?php echo get_permalink($p['ID']) ?>" style="font-weight: 600;">         
  <?php echo $p['post_title']?></a><br />
    </div>
    <?php
   }
  ?>
```

The code basically just loops through all the recent posts and then displays the thumbnail and title and supposedly the badge with the category its from within it. However I can't seem to understand why the get_the_category() function doesn't want to get anything and display it within the $category variable.

Comment: If you don't pass in a post ID to get_the_category(), it defaults to the page you're on. Are you calling this from an actual post? If not, you need to pass $p['ID'] to it.

Comment: I've tried passing it through $p['ID'] and I get this error: https://gyazo.com/056f822916d684a5044c640f784ece77

Comment: That's because it's trying to echo a `WP_Term` object in `echo $category` - try `echo $category->name` instead.

Comment: I added it as an answer rather than just a comment so it's a bit more visible to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the post's ID to `get_the_category()` and echo the category's name (since it's a WP_Term object):

```
foreach(get_the_category($p['ID']) as $category) {
   echo $category->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding $p['ID'] within get_category() so its get_the_category($p['ID']) and seeing if this gets the category type for a post?

Comment: I've tried that and it just throws me this error which I don't understand: https://gyazo.com/056f822916d684a5044c640f784ece77